# Why is it that nobody on these sites is here to help?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, closed-questions

I've used a few of the Stack Exchange sites and I've noticed that instead of trying to help people with their problems and questions, all most people do is down vote questions for the slightest mistake or even put an important question on hold.

Comment: Do you think that this is yet another __important question__?

Comment: im just curious

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093708/can-anyone-bugfix-for-me is a horrible question.

Comment: I strongly recommend [reading this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). To get good answers, you need to ask a good question.

Comment: And [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050150/using-the-data-in-a-mysql-table-in-an-html-page) say: `could anyone perhaps have a fiddle with it to make it work?`

Comment: And [in this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951977/closing-pages-after-loging-in), you say: `if anyone could re-write the code to make it work that would be greatly appreciated`.  You should be glad that it's still open.

Comment: if you ask this way you should not wonder

Comment: and you prove my point. thank you internet

Comment: You seem to be missing the point. Many people at [SO] are here just to help; however, this is not a free coding service. You need to put forth some effort yourself. You should not just throw a dump of code at us and expect us to fix your problem. Show more effort, improve your questions, and try to break down your examples to the simplest form where the bug occurs. If you show effort, people are more likely to help. There are thousands of questions coming in daily, we just cannot do all of your work for you. That is what you are paid for or are going to school to learn.

Comment: @JoshMein I'm only here because I was told I can trade in my rep for bitcoins once I reach 1,000,000.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I see you have finished at least your first cup of caffeine. Your humour has improved since earlier :)

Comment: look josh, the last question i posted, i came here as a last resort. if you can suggest anywhere else to help me learn, it would be greatly appreciated. oh and that "chunk" was as much as i could break it down to.

Comment: @user2987355 There are certainly other places you could go for help, and many places will readily accept questions like you are asking. They may be worth trying, but I would recommend just working on improving your asking skills. The problem with places that accept questions like those so readily is it's hard to get good answers. Personally, I can't recommend any of them.

Comment: First of all, you just ask us to fix your bug and provide a dump of the code. You did not tell us what you were trying to accomplish, why it isnt working, or maybe even a specific error you are receiving. Help yourself out by providing more information to us. Please provide any necessary information that may be required to answer your question.

Comment: @user2987355 Your last question doesn't even explain what you're trying to do! How are we supposed to know what you want your code to do?

Comment: thanks but it seems im clearly on the wrong site. one last point before i leave though, why is it that this site seems, from the outside at least, to be so friendly but is actual so 'strict'? is it just really good marketing?

Comment: Have you looked at how many questions we have on this site. The site has only been up for a little more than 5 years yet we have over 6 million questions. With so many questions, it is hard to help everyone, especially when they do not want to put forth any effort themselves. The more effort you show; the more effort we will show.

Comment: I agree with you that some people are not always friendly, but how good of a mood would you be if you were bombarded with please debug this code dump questions constantly. I enjoy helping others when they have put forth the effort, but when it seems like they just want me to do their work for them it is easy to get fed up with it. We will be glad to help. Just put in the effort. Provide more information. Most of the time more effort on your part will result in better acceptance of your questions and in turn better answers.

Comment: The site seems inviting because you find a lot of good content and great answers on it. It is very useful and people get great answers. Just what you were looking for. When you look closer you find out that the reason for all those good questions/answers is that bad/unclear/unhelpful/... questions/answers aren't well liked. The site is not very friendly to bad content, that is the reason why there isn't all that much of that on the site. So if you start posting unclear and not well thought through questions, you find that the site isn't very inviting *to that kind of content*.

Comment: If your assertion were true, there wouldn't be many answers at all on the site. Look at other questions - particularly those with some upvotes (which generally indicates that it's a good question). You'll usually find plenty of people happy to help there. In other words, the quality and quantity of help you're likely to receive is correlated with the quality of the question. Ask better questions, get better help - it's as simple as that. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://tinyurl.com/so-list for some guidance.

Comment: Once again, the system has been proven to be working correctly.

Answer (score 10):

Like most of your questions on SE, you've shown little to no effort in quantifying your question/statement here.  As someone pointed out above, Stack Overflow is a **community** site.  Yes, there are some employees, but 99.99% of us are just regular people like yourself who have a bit of a "philanthropist" streak in them and just want to be able to help people.  We are more than happy to help, as evidenced by the many thousands of answered questions here, but we also have jobs/school/families and we can't dedicate our lives to writing code for free.  Show a little initiative, narrow down your problem to one block of code, and I guarantee you will get an answer quickly.  Ask us to do your whole job with little-to-no understanding of what you're actually doing, and we're going to move on to another question.  Sorry, it just works that way.